# function in python for searching posible combination for specific name in a big file

Tags: python, string, pandas, join, group-by

I have a huge file(50,000 row) with 2 columns(id and name). One id can have different names but I am only looking for specific names and their ids.This specific name might have any combination with each other which I need to check whole file for any possible combination they came together.
I wrote the following function it gives me no error but it is not working neither.

I also want to count any combination of these names.

By the way I am using pandas and importing data as data frame.

for example:

```
id  name
a    TD
a    NB
a    LB
b    LR
b    NB
c    LR
c    NB
d    LB
```

I want result like:

```
a  TD,NB,LR  # they might have any combination I just wrote them as example
b  NB,LR
c  NB,LR
d  LB
```

and for counting I want:

```
TD,NB,LR 1
NB,LR    2
LB       1


def Gene_count(df_file):
    df_group_id = df.groupby('id').name
    for j in df_group_id:
            j = df.id
    for i in df_group_id:
    if i == 'TD' or i=='NB' or i=='LR' or i== 'LB':
                 print(i,j)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['name'].apply(','.join)
print (df1)
id
a    TD,NB,LB
b       LR,NB
c       LR,NB
d          LB
Name: name, dtype: object
```

and then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (df1.value_counts())
LR,NB       2
LB          1
TD,NB,LB    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

If want filter some values in concatenated output use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `join` `|` (regex `or`) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['name'].apply(','.join)

df2 = df1[df1.str.contains('|'.join(['LR','NB']))]
print (df2)
id
a    TD,NB,LB
b       LR,NB
c       LR,NB
Name: name, dtype: object

print (df2.value_counts())
LR,NB       2
TD,NB,LB    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Another possible solution is filter before with double [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
#get all id where is value LR or NB (unique is for better performance)
ids = df.loc[df.name.isin(['LR','NB']), 'id'].unique()
print (ids)
['a' 'b' 'c']

#filter by ids
df3 = df[df.id.isin(ids)]
print (df3)
  id name
0  a   TD
1  a   NB
2  a   LB
3  b   LR
4  b   NB
5  c   LR
6  c   NB

df4 = df3.groupby('id')['name'].apply(','.join)
print (df4)
id
a    TD,NB,LB
b       LR,NB
c       LR,NB
Name: name, dtype: object

print (df4.value_counts())
LR,NB       2
TD,NB,LB    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

I was really interested about performance of both solutions - it is same:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L1 = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.choice(L1, N), 
                   'name': np.random.choice(L1, N)})

In [31]: %timeit (df.groupby('id')['name'].apply(','.join))
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit (df.groupby('id')['name'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.tolist())))
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop
```

Comment: what i can do to not be case sensitive? for example there is no difference between 'nb' and 'NB' but it get them as 2 different things.

Comment: I think the simplier is before convert all values to lower by `df.name = df.name.str.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupby` on `id` and use `apply` to `join` the list.

```
In [45]: id_counts = df.groupby('id')['name'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.tolist()))

In [46]: id_counts
Out[46]:
id
a    TD,NB,LB
b       LR,NB
c       LR,NB
d          LB
Name: name, dtype: object
```

And then use `value_counts`, to count the values.

```
In [47]: id_counts.value_counts()
Out[47]:
LR,NB       2
TD,NB,LB    1
LB          1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```